# How to detect impending user touch before it happens?

Tags: arduino, sensor, proximity-sensor, esp32, capactive

I would like to detect an impending human touch on my microcontroller (I use an ESP32) - before it happens and setoff some kind of beeper (*nasty humans, yees... touching electronics when you know you shouldn't*). **TL;TR: How can I reliably detect the presence of a finger within 0-3cm of my device?**

Conditions

1. it should allow for omnidirectional sensing of 'hand' distance (<3cm would be sufficient)
2. the device size should ideally remain as small as possible (e.g. size of arduino nano)
3. should be implementable/interface-able with an arduino-like microcontroller and provide a readout of the range

Here are the methods I could come up with to go about solving this problem practically with some pro's and con's (mostly the latter):

- sound based: Several ultrasonic sensors (e.g. the [hc-sr04](https://www.google.com/search?q=ultrasonic%20sensor)) mounted. This would probably have some 'holes' in detection even if one sensor per cardinal direction is mounted. Sensors also tend to be somewhat large.
- electromagnetic frequency/light based (sorted by typical wavelength band):

  - laser-based: not omnidirectional.
  - IR based: might be affected by daylight
  - far IR based: common sensors don't seem to be optimally suited for short distances, and usually they are quite large (this may also be just due to the Freznel lens, but this would allow omnidirectional sensing to my understanding)
  - microwave or 'radar' based: might be optimal, but common, affordable sensors seem to have issues for
    omnidirectional sensing (e.g. [RCWL-0516](https://www.google.com/search?q=RCWL-0516)). Also seem to have issues with short range detection.
- capacitive: seems to work well for certain kinds of applications (like the musical instrument [theremin](https://www.google.com/search?q=theremin)). Apparently needs to be calibrated a lot though (imagine chip lying on a metal surface, or you taking your shoes off - apparently this varies signal strength greatly and could lead to false positives - i.e. chip beeping for no reason) - and apparently requires an antenna.

Questions:

1. Are there any known methods that I have not discovered (see list above, that I will update), or any ideas that my imagination and googling skills seemed to have lacked to come up with?
2. Is there any recommended method, from an theoretical engineering principle side (and feasibility/practicality side) to do this? I.e. would you recommend any method listed above for this problem?
3. currently, I would tend towards a capacitive sensor for this approach - however I seem to be lacking some kind of integrated circuit (IC) that would allow me to do this easily. [This, old article](https://spolearninglab.com/curriculum/workshops/physical_computing/2009/capacitive_sensor.html) a bit more, but it's unclear how much calibration is needed and how well this would work. Then another question remains, can this be optimized using the ESP32 (or any other) touch sensors?

Comment: [Farnell - PIR Sensors](https://uk.farnell.com/c/sensors-transducers/sensors/motion-sensors-position-sensors/pir-motion-sensors)

Comment: Detecting an event before it happens requires time-lord engineering.

Comment: @Andyaka ehm... well in this case the event is the user approaching the device to a given radius (1-3cm). But, yes, technically speaking, I agree in resp. to time-lord. Take it with a grain of salt, I'm a noob in electronics =)

Comment: The easiest and most reliable fix is by engineering a physical barrier. Why can't you do this?

Comment: a bit multipurpose here, I was also going to setup some user-interaction, e.g. make beeper sound different the closer you get. I thought first step would be best to just have a 0 or 1 detection. It's possible this is a question that suffers from an [XY issues](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: ST and others do "time of flight" sensors intended to track nearby eg hands without contact. [TOF search](https://www.google.com/search?q=st+time+of+flight+sensors&rlz=1C1CHBF_enNZ834NZ839&oq=st+time+of+flight+sensor&aqs=chrome.0.0i457j69i57j0i22i30l6.6398j0j9&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

Comment: [ST offering](https://www.st.com/en/imaging-and-photonics-solutions/proximity-sensors.html) and [ST presentation](https://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/sales_and_marketing/presentation/product_presentation/group0/e0/84/0c/fb/11/ec/49/1d/SensorsLive_LiDAR_Chip/files/SensorsLive_LiDAR_Chip.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.SensorsLive_LiDAR_Chip.pdf) - 33 pages

Comment: @RussellMcMahon interesting, and thanks for the reply. If i see correctly it's the TOF is IR technology with a max angle of 27°, I was ideally looking for something omnidirectonal. Can this be achieved with TOF?

Comment: @user2305193 I imagine that useful angle is based more on optics of TX & RX than the TOF method. There are sensors available from a range of manufacturers and it seems likely that if you are adequately keen [tm] you could increase the angle with external lensing. People are claiming up to 4 metres range with some ST units so you can probably tradeoff optical lensing loss for range and still get acceptable range.

Comment: [This image search](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22time+of+flight%22+sensors+%22tof%22&tbm=isch&ved=2ahUKEwj0ruWR093sAhU-_TgGHXe_AXgQ2-cCegQIABAA&oq=%22time+of+flight%22+sensors+%22tof%22&gs_lcp=CgNpbWcQAzoECCMQJzoECAAQHlDlUliYgwFgvYUBaABwAHgAgAGtAYgBqgqSAQMwLjiYAQCgAQGqAQtnd3Mtd2l6LWltZ8ABAQ&sclient=img&ei=z7mcX7SLCr764-EP9_6GwAc&bih=1057&biw=2048&rlz=1C1CHBF_enNZ834NZ839)    is probably a reasonable place to start looking both for devices and ideas. Each image links to a web page.

Comment: simple IR sensors (IR sensor+ IR LED) would tolerate dalight with adequate filtering. no direct sunlight though.

Comment: I don't know how they work, but nowadays there are touch-less soap and paper towel dispensers that mostly work OK. Seems like reliable technology and I am guessing it is not very expensive considering where it is embedded.

Answer (score 2):

For capacitive sensor check PIC12F1822/23 from Microchip.
You can also try an accelerometer as sensor. I created some device, connecting analog accelerometer module to ADC input MC and it senses even light touch.
Also you can try some barometric sensor or electret microphone. It will sense pressure change from air move.
Active sensors, like ultrasound and laser
may not fit your application because they have dead zone.
Infrared sensor like  AD8833 can be useful too, but it needs processing image.